# Deleting first few characters from specific records from r column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with column that has numbers. 
I need to delete first 2 characters in some cases & first characters for some of them.

```
DF$code

Code
1-731-770-3820
(464)424
217-008
```

Here , from first record i need to delete 1-.
from second record i need to delete (.
Third record is good.

Output should be

```
Code
731-770-3820
464)424
217-008
```

I have 50000+ such mixed records.
I was trying using gsub , but its deleting first character from the records which are already in good shape.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
DF$Code <- sub("^(1-|\\()", "", DF$Code)
DF$Code
#[1] "731-770-3820" "464)424"      "217-008"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. I can see its filtering data . but its becoming large character value. I tried to convert it with as.data.frame but its still taking all values in one single record after converting into dataframe.

Comment: Hey akrun , Thanks for the help. I was able to convert it into df properly . Cheers, ES.